# Can GWT apps be deployed with blue/green deployment?

Tags: java, gwt, load-balancing, requestfactory, blue-green-deployment

I read Martin Fowler's [Blue/Green Deployment](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) article and really like it. Basically, it's the concept that you have 2 production-class environments: a "blue" LIVE environment and a "green" LIVE environment. You only have 1 environment considered to be the "real" LIVE environment at any given time. So you put some sort of routing/switch mechanism (probably an intermediary web app or a modified software load balancer) in front of these two LIVE environments that dictates which environment users get routed to (we're talking web apps here).

So you have all your users getting routed to, say, the Green LIVE environment at `http://green.example.com/myapp`. Then, when you are ready to push out some new production changes, instead of deploying them to Green LIVE, you deploy them to Blue LIVE, and start routing some small (~10%) percentage of your users over to the Blue LIVE. Typical strategies are to have the router use IP addresses or cookies to determine whether a user should be routed to Blue or Green.

When you're confident that there are no bug bugs/issues with your production changes (applied to on Blue LIVE), you reconfigure the router to now have all traffic redirected to Blue LIVE at `http://blue.example.com/myapp`.

**Now, onto my question:**

I am designing a GWT app and would like to implement this blue/green switch pattern. The problem is that GWT apps are client-side and don't follow the normal server-side web app architecture that Spring, Struts, JSP, servlet apps utilize.

So I ask: how could I have 2 Tomcat instances (Blue Tomcat and Green Tomcat), serving two different versions of the same GWT app to users from behind a blue/green "router"? By "router", I'm probably talking about an intermediary web app at `http://router.example.com/myapp-router`.

Visually, here's the problem:

```
green.example.com:8080/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war/  --> Green Tomcat
    myModule/
        mymodule.nocache.js
        mymodule.cache.html    } typical GWT app WAR structure...
    hosts/                       this is currently the "real" LIVE
        index.html               environment where 90% traffic is routed to
    css/
        main.css
    WEB-INF/
        web.xml
        lib/
        classes/

blue.example.com:8080/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war/  --> Blue Tomcat
    myModule/
        mymodule.nocache.js
        mymodule.cache.html    } typical GWT app WAR structure...
    hosts/                       new production changes have been deployed here
        index.html               and 10% of users are routed here
    css/
        main.css
    WEB-INF/
        web.xml
        lib/
        classes/

router.example.com:8080/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp-router.war/  --> Router
    WEB-INF/
        web.xml
        lib/          }    simple headless WAR that inspects HTTP Requests and
        classes/           determines which environment to redirect user to
```

That's the basic architecture: the problem is that clients would be making requests to `router.example.com/myapp-router`, and the router would be forwarding the requests on to either `blue.example.com/myapp` or `green.example.com/myapp`. I'm not convinced that GWT (I'm using **RequestFactory** here) will ultimately know to communicate with either `blue` or `green` once the GWT app is downloaded to the client.

So I ask: is this possible? Are there any special configurations/code/libs/techniques etc. I will need to utilize in order to make this work? Any caveats or pitfalls I'm not thinking of? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The deployment process you describe is really canary deployment (incremental), not blue-green deployment (all at once). That doesn't invalidate your question, but it needs revision.

Answer (score 1):

The same preparations for deployment are needed regardless of deployment strategy: blue-green, canary (see your other question, [Canary release strategy vs. Blue/Green](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746038/canary-release-strategy-vs-blue-green/24015414), for a discussion of the differences) or upgrading a single server. A single client's browser-level view of a successful upgrade is the same: each request sees the old version, deployment happens, each request now sees the new version. Similarly, a single client's browser-level view of a failed upgrade and rollback is the same.

When I worked with a GWT app several years ago our strategy was to catch the exceptions that GWT throws when it encounters a new, incompatible version on the server and show the user a message asking them to refresh their browser. This article gives a little more detail: http://codebetter.com/kylebaley/2012/01/06/deploying-a-new-version-of-a-gwt-app-2/ It also mentions that if you use Google App Engine you can use GAE's Channel API to detect that a new version of your app has been released and then ask the user to refresh. But again, whatever strategy you follow, it applies to any deployment process.